# Spring Data JPA Repository findAll() Null Pointer

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring-Boot API with the endpoint below. It is throwing a Null Pointer Exception on a Spring Data JPA `findAll` query; when I comment out this line, I get no errors. It seems that I am getting a null result from the repository query, but I know the data is there from querying the DB directly. I cannot understand why I'm getting a null for `topicsLookup` variable... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Resource:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lectures/{lectureId}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, SpeakerTopicLectures> getLecture(@PathVariable Long lectureId){

        Long requestReceived = new Date().getTime();
        Map<String, SpeakerTopicLectures> result = new HashMap<>();

        log.debug("** GET Request to getLecture");
        log.debug("Querying results");

        List<SpeakerTopicLectures> dataRows = speakerTopicLecturesRepository.findBySpeakerTopicLecturesPk_LectureId(lectureId);

        // This line throws the error
        List<SpeakerTopic> topicsLookup = speakerTopicsRepository.findAll();

        // Do stuff here...

        log.debug("Got {} rows", dataRows.size());
        log.debug("Request took {}ms **", (new Date().getTime() - requestReceived));

        // wrap lecture in map object
        result.put("content", dataRows.get(0));

        return result;
}
```

**Java Bean:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "speaker_topics")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class SpeakerTopic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "topic_id")
    private Long topicId;

    @Column(name = "topic_nm")
    private String topicName;

    @Column(name = "topic_desc")
    private String topicDesc;

    @Column(name = "topic_acm_relt_rsce")
    private String relatedResources;

}
```

**Repository:**

```
import org.acm.dl.api.domain.SpeakerTopic;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SpeakerTopicsRepository extends JpaRepository<SpeakerTopic,Long> {

}
```

Comment: If any more information would be helpful, let me know and I will try to provide it.

Comment: A stacktrace might help. Can you confirm that speakerTopicsRepository itself is not null - have you @Autowired it?

Comment: @NickJ That was it. I forgot the `@Inject` annotation.  Feel free to post as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `speakerTopicsRepository` is itself null, which is probably caused by forgetting to autowire it, e.g.

```
public class YourController {

  @Autowired private SpeakerTopicsRepository speakerTopicsRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/lectures/{lectureId}",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Map<String, SpeakerTopicLectures> getLecture(@PathVariable Long lectureId) {
     // your method...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the repository is not autowired in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface SpeakerTopicsRepository extends JpaRepository<SpeakerTopic,Long> {
    // Your Repository Code 
}
```

I think `@Repository` & `@Transactional` is missing. Please use it.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 1):

It was missing @Autowired for me.